# Open Facebook app on login, how does Uber do it?

Tags: ios, facebook

How does Uber open Facebook app, when user is login in with facebook?

In my case, I have a project with iOS8 deployment target, 4.16 FBSDK and app always opens SafariView, which [is done by design, I guess](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/10/29/Facebook-Login-iOS9/)?

Does Uber use an old SKD or I am simply using FBSDK wrong?
This is how I login. I even set to use native app.

```
fbLoginManager.loginBehavior = .Native 
fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email", "public_profile", "user_birthday"], fromViewController: vc) { (result, error) in...
```

And I've modified plist according to [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9)

Answer (score 0):

Facebook previously open the Facebook native app if it was installed in your device.

But From iOS9, This is now the default behaviour for Facebook SSO.

According to them opening Facebook in Safari is a better UI experience for users. By modifying keys in .plist will not help to open native app.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/10/29/Facebook-Login-iOS9/

> For apps on iOS 8 and below, Facebook Login checks to see if the
>   Facebook app is installed on the device. If the app is installed, the
>   SDK switches to the Facebook app via a fast-app-switch to display the
>   Login experience.

Check in Which iOS version, you are checking Uber app. But as far as it concern, you will get logged in properly using browser too.

You can use old sdk to achieve this functionality.

If you are using Facebook SDK v4.6, It will use Safari view controller by default.

Try using a version of the SDK v4.5 or older and all the settings in plist according to it. For more information on this regarding plist and code for SDK v4.5 you can checkout this link : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

Comment: iOS version of the device? iOS 9 and Uber always opens native app, not browser. Secondly Facebook claims Safari is better UI experience in the long run, because every time app wants to switch to other app it should ask permission, but that's not always true, like Facebook and its messenger, they always switch but don't show any alerts. Or google maps.

Comment: Then uber must be using old sdk.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, but it was resolved when I turned my Facebook App (on the Facebook dev site) live.

When it was in dev mode, it did the SSO in Safari, and when released it did it through the native app

Comment: Unfortunately in my case Facebook is live